# How can I keep track of my CircleCI build minutes usage?

Tags: continuous-integration, circleci

I'm currently trialling the free tier of CircleCI on their Linux build machines. They claim to offer:

- 1,500 build minutes per month
- 1 container
- 1 concurrent build

I've added some repos and done some builds, but there does not seem to be any way to keep track of my minutes usage. In the short term I doubt I will go over this generous limit, but it might be possible in the future, and I'd like to keep an eye on that before I put too much effort into building around this CI system.

The only thing that looks relevant is the screen `Settings > Plan > Overview`, which looks like this:

[image: CircleCI screenshot]

It says my usage data will be updated within 30 days. Does that mean I have to wait for the end of the billing period every month to see what my usage was? I want to see my usage data in real time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aha, I found an old answer [here, in a customer support forum](https://discuss.circleci.com/t/free-account-build-minutes/1125/8). From an employee from October 2016. It seems to be the case that, at least previously, this feature was not supported:

> From time to time, we look at the logs and send emails to organizations that do not have paid plans and whose aggregate builds are more than 1,500 minutes in a given month. To date, we haven't had the need (or desire) to shut anyone down for going over. Most folks either upgrade or realize that they unintentionally left a webhook running on a project that builds constantly (which uses AWS resources that we still incur costs against!)
>
> As an organization, CircleCI cares that users get value out of their CI system. If you are getting value and using us for work that matters to you, hopefully you'll consider our paid options (you will get more containers for concurrency AND parallelism, you'll get engineer support, and features like Insights!).
>
> Finally - we do have plans to show linux minutes in-app in the future but it's not on the current quarter's roadmap.

However, a day or so after I took the screenshot in the question, the data has now populated:

[image: CircleCI screenshot showing container time]

I will keep an eye on this to see if it is indeed real-time, but it looks correct to me.

### Update

The usage facility has been [non-operational for two weeks](https://discuss.circleci.com/t/plan-overview-ajax-ops-seem-to-be-crashing-with-500-errors/18215), and [others have reported problems](https://discuss.circleci.com/t/free-plan-where-to-check-the-build-minutes-per-month/11301/4) as well.

While this may be fixed in due course, it may be worth bearing in mind that it seems to be fragile, so open your Network tab if you're having problems!